# XMPP connecting to server (Python)

Tags: python, xmpp, bots

I am currently following a tutorial/getting started on [creating a Google Talk Bot](http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/echobot.html)

I have made the EchoBot but it fails at runtime with the following error:

```
File "echobot.py", line 59, in <module>
if xmpp.connect(('talk.google.com'), '5222'):
File "C:\Python31\Lib\sleekxmpp\clientxmpp.py", line 143, in connect
reattempt=reattempt)
File "C:\Python31\Lib\sleekxmpp\xmlstream\xmlstream.py", line 372, in connect
self.address = (host, int(port))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

I have tried Python 3,3 , 3,2 and 3,1 interpreter with the same result.

I can not get these lines from the tutorial to compile with either of the compilers:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

The code from within the Bot where it fails is as follows:

```
if xmpp.connect(('talk.google.com'), '5222'):
    xmpp.process(block=True)
else:
    print('Fekk ikkje kopla til')
```

Thanks for any tips/help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written something wrong:

```
xmpp.connect(('talk.google.com', '5222'))
                               |
                             there you missed a comma
```

and the second thing could be to put the port to the second place.

```
xmpp.connect(('talk.google.com', 5222), '5222')
```

I do not know of the second argument but

**Internet Adresses** are almost always tuples of `(HOST, PORT)`

Comment: Thank you, it was the comma! Appreciated. This worked: xmpp.connect(('talk.google.com', '5222')):